# getDefinitionByName xml variable not defined

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Changing my file structure has caused problems with the function that creates the classes using data from an XML file. I am aware that the full package needs to be displayed but I must be doing it wrong.

I get this as an error....

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable WoodlandBG is not defined.
```

I have created a variable for the bG1 and data-typed it to a `Background` class....the class that is created in the `game.Game` class recalls information loaded into the `levelXML` (`game.backgrounds.WoodlandBG.as` called through from `_app.levelXl`)

```
var bgType:String = _app.levelXML.@bg;

trace(bgType);//this returns WoodlandBG
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName('.game.backgrounds.' + bgType) as Class;

trace(classRef);//this is not returning anything

bG1 = new classRef(this);
bG1.y = 0;
addChild(bG1);

trace(bG1);
```

Comment: Is WoodlandBG referenced anywhere in the AS3 code?  If not the class will not be compiled into the SWF and therefore won't be available at run time.  Simply including an import or "WoodlandBG;" in a file will be sufficient to cause it to be compiled and linked into the swf.

Comment: I had all that included into the class where the WoodlandBg is instantiated, I have since resorted back to my old way of organising everything. It works but doesn't look pretty...I will have another go later at messing around with the packages but thanks for the response.

Comment: Why is there a dot before game in `'.game.background.'`?